Unable to create Dependency Injection for cosmosdb for multiple environments in c#
I am new to C# and attempting to implement Dependency Injection in the Program.cs file.
Program.cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICosmosClientFactory, CosmosClientFactory>();

ICosmosClientFactory.cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace TestApplication.Interfaces
{
    public interface ICosmosClientFactory
    {
        CosmosClient CreateClient(string environment);
    }
}

CosmosClientFactory.cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using System.Net;
using MSaaSPartnerOnboarding.Interfaces;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Azure.Identity;

namespace TestApplication.Models
{
    public class CosmosClientFactory : ICosmosClientFactory
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public CosmosClientFactory(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates and configures a new instance of the <see cref="CosmosClient"/> class 
        /// using settings from the specified environment and Azure Managed Identity for authentication.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="environment">The environment name to retrieve CosmosDB settings from the configuration.</param>
        /// <returns>A configured <see cref="CosmosClient"/> instance.</returns>
        /// <remarks>
        /// The method reads CosmosDB settings from the application configuration based on the specified environment. 
        /// It uses <see cref="DefaultAzureCredential"/> with a user-assigned managed identity for authentication. 
        /// The CosmosClientOptions are configured with specific connection mode, port reuse mode, and retry policies.
        /// </remarks>
        public CosmosClient CreateClient(string environment)
        {
            var cosmosDbSettings = _configuration.GetSection(environment).GetChildren()
                .ToDictionary(section => section.Key, section => section.Value);

            var cosmosClientOptions = new CosmosClientOptions
            {
                ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                PortReuseMode = PortReuseMode.PrivatePortPool,
                EnableContentResponseOnWrite = false,
                MaxRetryWaitTimeOnRateLimitedRequests = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_configuration.GetValue<int>("MaxRetryWaitTime")),
                MaxRetryAttemptsOnRateLimitedRequests = _configuration.GetValue<int>("MaxRetryAttempts"),
                RequestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_configuration.GetValue<int>("RequestTimeout"))
            };

            var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                ManagedIdentityClientId = cosmosDbSettings["UserAssignedManagedIdentity"],
                ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential = true,
                ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = true,
                ExcludeAzureCliCredential = true
            });

            var cosmosDBAccountName = cosmosDbSettings["CosmosDBAccountName"];
            return new CosmosClient($"https://{cosmosDBAccountName}.documents.azure.com:443/", tokenCredential, cosmosClientOptions);
        }
    }
}

The code is functioning as expected, retrieving Cosmos details based on the selected environment.
However, my requirement is to compile all the details for CosmosDB accounts, including database names and container details, for each environment individually while loading the application (Means Program.cs should handle this in DI). I need to be able to use this information immediately. I attempted the following approach, but unfortunately, I wasn't able to retrieve the details successfully.
My Approaches in Program.cs
static void CreateClient(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    var environments = new[] { "WWPPE", "WWProd", "EUPPE", "EUProd" };
    foreach (var environment in environments)
    {
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<CosmosClient>(provider =>
        {
            var configuration = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

            var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                ManagedIdentityClientId = configuration[$"{environment}:UserAssignedManagedIdentity"],
                ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential = true,
                ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = true,
                ExcludeAzureCliCredential = true
            });

            var options = new CosmosClientOptions
            {
                ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                PortReuseMode = PortReuseMode.PrivatePortPool,
                EnableContentResponseOnWrite = false,
                MaxRetryWaitTimeOnRateLimitedRequests = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(configuration.GetValue<int>("MaxRetryWaitTime")),
                MaxRetryAttemptsOnRateLimitedRequests = configuration.GetValue<int>("MaxRetryAttempts"),
                RequestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(configuration.GetValue<int>("RequestTimeout"))
            };

            var cosmosDBAccountName = configuration[$"{environment}:CosmosDBAccountName"];
            var agentViewCosmos = configuration[$"{environment}:BaseUrl"];

            return new CosmosClient(agentViewCosmos, tokenCredential, options);
        });
    }
}

Approach 2:
static void AddCosmos(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddAzureClients(factoryBuilder =>
    {
        // Register a client using MyApplicationOptions to get constructor parameters
        factoryBuilder.AddClient<CosmosClient, CosmosClientOptions>((options, credential, provider) =>
        {
            var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                ManagedIdentityClientId = builder.Configuration["dev:UserAssignedManagedIdentity"],
                ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential = true,
                ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = true,
                ExcludeAzureCliCredential = true
            });

            CosmosClientOptions cosmosClientOptions = new CosmosClientOptions()
            {
                ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                PortReuseMode = PortReuseMode.PrivatePortPool,
                EnableContentResponseOnWrite = false,
                MaxRetryWaitTimeOnRateLimitedRequests = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_configuration.GetValue<int>("MaxRetryWaitTime")),
                MaxRetryAttemptsOnRateLimitedRequests = _configuration.GetValue<int>("MaxRetryAttempts"),
                RequestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_configuration.GetValue<int>("RequestTimeout"))
            };
            var agentViewCosmos = builder.Configuration["dev:BaseUrl"];
            return new CosmosClient(agentViewCosmos, credential, options);
        }).WithCredential(tokenCredential)
        .WithName("dev");

        factoryBuilder.AddClient<CosmosClient, CosmosClientOptions>((options, credential, provider) =>
        {
            var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                ManagedIdentityClientId = builder.Configuration["test:UserAssignedManagedIdentity"],
                ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential = true,
                ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = true,
                ExcludeAzureCliCredential = true
            });

            CosmosClientOptions cosmosClientOptions = new CosmosClientOptions()
            {
                ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                PortReuseMode = PortReuseMode.PrivatePortPool,
                EnableContentResponseOnWrite = false,
                MaxRetryWaitTimeOnRateLimitedRequests = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_configuration.GetValue<int>("MaxRetryWaitTime")),
                MaxRetryAttemptsOnRateLimitedRequests = _configuration.GetValue<int>("MaxRetryAttempts"),
                RequestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_configuration.GetValue<int>("RequestTimeout"))
            };
            var agentViewCosmos = builder.Configuration["test:BaseUrl"];
            return new CosmosClient(agentViewCosmos, credential, options);
        }).WithCredential(tokenCredential)
        .WithName("test");

        factoryBuilder.AddClient<CosmosClient, CosmosClientOptions>((options, credential, provider) =>
        {
            var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                ManagedIdentityClientId = builder.Configuration["PreProd:UserAssignedManagedIdentity"],
                ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential = true,
                ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = true,
                ExcludeAzureCliCredential = true
            });

            CosmosClientOptions cosmosClientOptions = new CosmosClientOptions()
            {
                ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                PortReuseMode = PortReuseMode.PrivatePortPool,
                EnableContentResponseOnWrite = false,
                MaxRetryWaitTimeOnRateLimitedRequests = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_configuration.GetValue<int>("MaxRetryWaitTime")),
                MaxRetryAttemptsOnRateLimitedRequests = _configuration.GetValue<int>("MaxRetryAttempts"),
                RequestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_configuration.GetValue<int>("RequestTimeout"))
            };
            var agentViewCosmos = builder.Configuration["PreProd:BaseUrl"];
            return new CosmosClient(agentViewCosmos, credential, options);
        }).WithCredential(tokenCredential)
        .WithName("PreProd");

        factoryBuilder.AddClient<CosmosClient, CosmosClientOptions>((options, credential, provider) =>
        {
            var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                ManagedIdentityClientId = builder.Configuration["Prod:UserAssignedManagedIdentity"],
                ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential = true,
                ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = true,
                ExcludeAzureCliCredential = true
            });

            CosmosClientOptions cosmosClientOptions = new CosmosClientOptions()
            {
                ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                PortReuseMode = PortReuseMode.PrivatePortPool,
                EnableContentResponseOnWrite = false,
                MaxRetryWaitTimeOnRateLimitedRequests = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_configuration.GetValue<int>("MaxRetryWaitTime")),
                MaxRetryAttemptsOnRateLimitedRequests = _configuration.GetValue<int>("MaxRetryAttempts"),
                RequestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_configuration.GetValue<int>("RequestTimeout"))
            };
            var agentViewCosmos = builder.Configuration["Prod:BaseUrl"];
            return new CosmosClient(agentViewCosmos, credential, options);
        }).WithCredential(tokenCredential)
        .WithName("Prod");
    });
}


Could you share any error or issue you are facing while running the code?

Hi @Balaji, Thanks for your response. When I run the application, I don't see any error messages, and the debugger doesn't hit the code. The debugger skips over it and only hits the breakpoints before and after this code.
